# C# error CS1061. get method name

Tags: c#, .net, linux, methods, .net-core

I wrote this code in visual studion on windows:

```
public static double timeTest(Func<List<int>, List<int>> method, int len)
{
    System.Console.Write(String.Format("Testing {0} for {1} elements...\n", method.Method.Name, len));
    /*snipped*/
}
```

And it works fine and produced output like:

```
Testing foo for 500 elements...
```

But then i tried to build this code on linux with `dotnet-cli`, it failed compilation with this error:

```
/home/puck/lab6/Program.cs(22,92): error CS1061: 'Func<List<int>, List<int>>' 
does not contain a definition for 'Method' and no extension method 'Method' 
accepting a first argument of type 'Func<List<int>, List<int>>' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So, what is the problem?

P.S: fixed my problem by replacing `method.Method.Name` with `System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetMethodInfo(method).Name`

Comment: What .net version did you successfully compile it against? Try `method.GetMethod()` instead

Comment: @KMoussa, Same error: `error CS1061: 'Func<List<int>, List<int>>' does not contain a definition for 'GetMethod' /*snipped*/ `

Comment: Sorry I remembered the method name wrong, have a look at the answer in the possible duplicate, it's `GetMethodInfo`

Comment: @KMoussa, same error. [Here is](https://vk.cc/5Sm4B5) screenshot what methods i can call with my method

Comment: Couldn't open screenshot. Are you getting error on the .net core or .net 4.5 now?

Comment: @KMoussa [reposted image](http://i.imgur.com/fyWPrgM.jpg). I'm getting error on .net core. On .net 4.5.2 all works fine

Comment: Thanks for the update